# hardware interrupt on arithmetic overflow?

Tags: math, hardware, overflow, cpu

Those of us who know the Carry and Overflow flag (lets not forget about sign and zero) love them.

My question is, is there a CPU that will interrupt if a carry or overflow flag is set? when it ask it to?

Its way better then having a branch after every arithmetic instruction...

Comment: I've never seen interrupt on carry. Overflow is probably not going to work out either. What specific problem are you facing? There may be other ways to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

On IA-32 CPUs you have the `INTO` instruction (that's the letter `O`, not the number `0`) that will go to interrupt handler 4 (#OF) if the overflow flag is set.

There is no equivalent instruction for the carry flag.

Note that this instruction is invalid in 64-bit mode.

Comment: C'est la vie, if you'll pardon my French.

Answer (score 1):

The MIPS cpu triggers an exception on overflow.

Comment: Nice. I looked up a little thing and it appears there is no carry. Is overflow used as carry as well? On the cpu i used overflow is when you add 2 signed ints and it wraps around. Carry is the same thing except its unsigned ints. For example `-1(255 unsigned) + -2(254 unsigned) = -3 (253 unsigned)` would cause a carry but not overflow. Is there something like a carry on MIPS?

Comment: More specifically, MIPS `add` / `sub` traps on signed overflow.  MIPS `addu` / `subu` doesn't.  C compilers normally use `addu` / `addiu` for everything so they can re-associate integer math, and because (historically) users more often wanted silent wrap-around than noisy failure.

Comment: There is no equivalent for trapping unsigned wraparound on MIPS, you'd have to do something like `sum = a+b;` `carry=sum<a;` (with `addu` / `sltu`) and branch on that (to a sequence of instructions that traps).  Or inline maybe `slli $t0, $t0, 31` / `add $t0, $t0, $t0` to trap on INT_MIN + INT_MIN overflowing to 0 if the SLTU result was `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The IBM 360 series CPUs and their successors provided an integer overflow interrupt, maskable by a bit in the PSW (Program Status Word), which could be modified in user mode by the instruction Set Program Mask.